# Where do I need to put the AIDL file?

Tags: android, service, aidl

Just one question concerning AIDL files, the context is that I'm writing a little project using another project as a library. In this library, a service is implemented and I'm trying to make a bind to it.
So my question is: if my service is in another project, do I have to put the AIDL file in mine too or is the existing AIDL from the other project enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found that I have to put it in my project that uses the service. I have to put it in exactly the same package name as the server as well. In additional, I am using parcelable, and I had to paste that parcelable implementation (java) file in too, in the same package as it were specified in the service project.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, btw I forgot I asked this question, thanks.